# To whom is the kaddish addressed?

Tags: tefilla

The first paragraph of the kaddish includes these words: "let His kingship be established in your lifetime and in your days..."

The question is, to whom is this part of the kaddish addressed?  Why does it not say "in our lifetime and in our days"?

Comment: 1 – מיוסד עפ"י המקרא: "והתגדלתי והתקדשתי" האמור במלחמת גוג ומגוג, שאחרי זה יתגדל שמו של הקב"ה, שנאמר: "ביום ההוא יהיה ה' אחד ושמו אחד". יאמר ברור: "יתגדל" ולא כאותם האומרים : "יתקדל". 2 – פירוש האמנים שבקדיש – כן יהי רצון. 3 – שתי תיבות, שלא יאמר: "דברא". 4 – בחייכם העתידיים לעולם הבא, וביומיכם העכשויים. 5 – החיים כיום, ושיחיו בתחיית המתים. וכן יש בזה גם בקשה שנזכה להיות מהנשארים בחיים בתקופת הגאולה. 6 – יש להפסיק מעט בין אמירת מילת "אמן", לבין "יהי שם וכו'". 7 – אמרו חז"ל (שבת קיט:): "כל האומ

Comment: http://www.breslevmeir.com/%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D that should answer your question but I am not sure its correct

Comment: It is addressed to those answering 'omen yehe' which is the whole purpose of kaddish. The more people, the greater the minyan the better. YOu have the zchus or your parents of making them say this. That is if they know what they are talking about.

Comment: @cham  I do not understand your comment with the Hebrew quotes.  Also, how the link helps is not clear to me.  The link also says You rather than We.  Would you please clarify.  Your third comment is interesting.  Is there any other part of our siddur where we address other people using You?

Comment: בחייכם העתידיים לעולם הבא, וביומיכם העכשויים. 5 – החיים כיום, ושיחיו בתחיית המתים. וכן יש בזה גם בקשה שנזכה להיות מהנשארים בחיים בתקופת הגאולה. 6 @Yehuda W is that what you want translating?

Comment: @cham  I do not see how what you wrote answers the question (to whom are we talking).  Perhaps it is a language problem: My understanding your Hebrew or you my English.

Comment: I may add it is wrong for two people to be saying kaddish like two people dont say borchu together.

Answer (score 2):

Alex [described here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4759/440) how Kaddish used to have an insert for prayers for the leaders of the community.

Shlomo Tal theorizes [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33655&st=&pgnum=144) that Yukum Purkan is an extraction from such inserts, but be that as it may, he quotes some interesting versions that put such prayers either before or after the "in your lifetime ..."

Note, this would put the comma after "May He establish His kingdom" as more of a parenthetical statement of let what we said previously happen in your lifetime. The [Chemdas Shmuel](https://books.google.com/books?id=qm9BAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT45&lpg=PT45#v=onepage&q&f=false) (by R. Shmuel Vital, the son of R. Chaim Vital, the primary transmitter of the Arizal's teachings) in his Kabbalistic explanations of Kaddish says that those words are a prayer, not part of the Kaddish proper, and thus he has no need to explain them Kabbalistically.

So it would seem that the it is a vestige of a blessing being given to others, namely the congregation and persons of importance present (or in the case of the Teimanim in Alex's answer not present) during the recitation of Kaddish.

Comment: Speaking of kaddish it is wrong to say too many. One should not say kaddish after 'anim zmirot' as well.