# invoking a name in prayer

Tags: tefilla

I am reading a book [A Jewish Woman's Prayer Book, by Aliza Lavie](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001FA0JXM).
In it the author writes:

> Freiha was an eighteenth-century Moroccan poet who wrote in Hebrew
>   under the pen-name Bat Yosef.  Respectfully referred to as Rabbanit,
>   she was a Torah scholar and life a legacy of writings and poems, few
>   of which have survived.  Her extensive library, including kabbalistic
>   works, testified to the breadth of her learning.  Women in her
>   community approached her as they would a saint, **often invoking her
>   name in times of distress.**

What does it mean, "invoking her name in times of distress?"

Comment: Probably "may the God of Freiha save me!"

Comment: What makes you say/think/know so?

Comment: A popular charity today is called "Rabbi Meir the Miracle Man." On the side of the box it says, "God of Meir, answer me!" That's about as close to sainthood that Orthodox Jews will go without getting *really* theologically murky.

Comment: By the merit of Frecha (please) answer!

Comment: Have you tried asking Dr. Lavie?

Comment: How would one ask her?

Comment: I found this that might relate:  http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/761128/jewish/Why-Use-the-Mothers-Name-When-Praying-for-Someone.htm

Comment: A variety of activities were practices legitimately or not (IMAO generally not, but that makes no difference) that utilized a variety of media as intermediaries of some sort for prayers. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/62647/8775 for one example and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56559/5083 for another example. Thus any number of possibilities exist for the case in question.

Comment: See here about the Yemenites adding a mention of the Rambam to Kaddish: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/what-do-we-know-about-the-yemenites-adding-deleting-maimonides-from-their-pra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a current practice, see [this text](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%9F) from Selichot "Merciful, **remember for us the** *alliance/ praying/ jealousy/ merit* **of**..." in Aramean.

Or as cited by Shalom, see this Selicha ("Answer us, G-d of/.../by merit of/ answer us!"):

> עֲנֵנוּ אֶלֹהֵי אַבְרָהָם עֲנֵנו:‏
>
> עֲנֵנוּ וּפַחַד יִצְחָק עֲנֵנוּ:‏
>
> עֲנֵנוּ אֲבִיר יַעֲקֹב עֲנֵנוּ:‏
>
> עֲנֵנוּ מָגֵן דָּוִד עֲנֵנוּ:‏
>
> עֲנֵנוּ הָעוֹנֶה בְּעֵת רָצוֹן עֲנֵנוּ:‏
>
> עֲנֵנוּ הָעוֹנֶה בְּעֵת צָרָה עֲנֵנוּ:‏
>
> עֲנֵנוּ הָעוֹנֶה בְּעֵת רַחֲמִים עֲנֵנוּ:‏
>
> עֲנֵנוּ אֱלֹהֵי הַמֶּרְכָּבָה עֲנֵנוּ:‏
>
> ***עֲנֵנוּ אֱלָהָא דְּמֵאִיר עֲנֵנוּ***:‏
>
> ***עננו בזכותיה דבר יוחאי עננו***:‏
>
> עננו משגב האמהות עננו:‏
>
> עננו עזרת השבטים עננו:‏
>
> עֲנֵנוּ רַחוּם וְחַנּוּן עֲנֵנוּ:‏